# Bundler using binstub generated for a different gem using Middleman

Tags: bundler, middleman

I am using Middleman to build a project. I receive this message any time I run a Middleman command:

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub middleman-core` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

When I run `bundle binstub middleman-core`, I get this:

```
middleman-core has no executables, but you may want one from a gem it depends on.
bundler has: bundle, bundler
rack has: rackup
tilt has: tilt
erubis has: erubis
listen has: listen
sass has: sass, sass-convert, scss
```

Don't really know where to go and what to do from that message.
It is not causing the anything to fail and the server runs, but I feel like this could be a bigger issue if I leave it unfixed. This ended up happening when I was playing with s3_sync to push this up to s3 bucket and I gem installed middleman-sync_s3.

I have tried research and others led me through the path of deleting the `bin/*` file multiple times. I've tried updating the `bin` also and neither helps.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was hopping around the Gemfile trying to figure out what was going on. I had built a few previous projects in middleman and decided to look them up. I saw that I was using a previous version of `Middleman 3.1.0` where as with this current project I was using `Middleman 4.0.0`

I reverted back to 3.1.0 and ran a `bundle update`. Tried running a Middleman command and the binstubs message no longer appears.

Ultimately, I think it had something with the way bundler plays with middleman-core.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install middleman-cli` seems to help in case someone else is looking for a solution to this.